# MySQL Group Elements and Count the Elements in each Group

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, count, where-in

I'm working on an assignment and my prompt is "List all teams founded before 2011 that are still active (not yet disbanded). For each such team, give the team name, date founded, and the number of current team members who play Protoss, Terran, and Zerg, respectively. Sort the teams alphabetically by name" Below is a picture of the database schema.[image: database schema]

My query is not properly grouping the members by their game race (Protoss, Terran, and Zerg). Instead, it is grouping the game races and outputting three rows per team one row for each game race, instead of three individual columns with respective values of game races and one row per team. Here is some sample data from the players.csv, teams.csv, members.csv, tournaments.csv, earnings.csv, and matches.csv.
[image: players.csv][image: members.csv][image: teams.csv][image: earnings.csv][image: matches.csv][image: tournaments.csv]

Here is my query.

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.founded
     , COUNT(p.game_race = '"P"')
     , COUNT(p.game_race = '"Z"')
     , COUNT(p.game_race = '"T"')
  FROM teams t 
     , members m
     , players p
 WHERE t.team_id = m.team 
   AND p.player_id = m.player 
 GROUP 
    BY t.name
     , p.game_race;
```

Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: Add some sample and expected data. Or give at least the structure of your table.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @cdaiga I added some sample data and the database schema.

Comment: @B.Mack the sample data is not suffiecient. Add some data from the other tables. Hope your dates are stored as date, not varchar?

Comment: @cdaiga I added some data from the other tables, and I am storing the dates as dates.

Comment: @B.Mack I am not seeing any data regarding: ` current team members who play Protoss, Terran, and Zerg`! So I think it is not yet complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should group the data base on the selected fields that are not aggregated. You should use SUM in this case as for example when `p.game_race='"P"'` is true 1 is return so we add one which is like counting that item. Using count for example `p.game_race='"P"'` is false 0 is return but since 0 is different from null it is counted which wrong. So try this:

```
SELECT t.name, t.found, 
SUM(p.game_race='"P"'),
SUM(p.game_race='"Z"'),
SUM(p.game_race='"T"')
FROM teams t LEFT JOIN member m
ON t.team_id = m.team LEFT JOIN players p
ON p.player_id = m.player
WHERE t.disbanded=0 AND t.founded<STR_TO_DATE('%d-%m-%Y','01-01-2011')
GROUP BY t.name, t.found
ORDER BY t.name;
```

Comment: I added some sample data and the database schema. Also, when I run this query it only returns zeros in the sum columns.